# Ubuntu disk will not mount

Tags: disk

Here is the error

```
Error mounting system-managed device /dev/sdb1: Command-line `mount "/mnt/287319a7-69ba-45b8-b8bf-e2fd4d6ea6f0"' exited with non-zero exit status 32: mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb1,
missing codepage or helper program, or other error
In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
dmesg | tail  or so
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**/dev/sdb1** disk will mount if you update your kernal.Run the below command on terminal to update linux kernal,

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic
```

These errors are caused mainly due to bugs in the kernal.Updating your kernal will solve this mounting problem.

Comment: I was running NADIA using a single Drive, added another drive and installed PETRA, figured I could try and recover files from the disk this way, new to Linux and not sure what to do just to get the bad drive to mount. Considering testdrive but not sure how to use. Tried Gparted (w parted algos) it had no luck, the drive does show up in the Computer, and does indicate 60 some bad sectors.

Comment: try `sudo badblocks -sv /dev/sdb1` to check for badblocks.

Comment: see this http://myhowtosandprojects.blogspot.in/2009/04/recovering-data-from-disks-with-bad.html to recover data from disks which contains badblocks.

Comment: Its checking... is there a way to run fsck on the bad disk (thinking I have to be able to mount it first)

Comment: `fsck /dev/sdb1`

Comment: Still checking 21% done, no bad blocks found yet. WRT to your first recommendation, "sudo apt-get install linux-generic" I'm assuming this should not be done the way I am currently installed, e.g., it could mess-up the PETRA install?

Comment: Avinash Raj, thanks for the help, the How To link and DDrescue manual have me on my way. http://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/manual/ddrescue_manual.html

Comment: After 2 hours of agony and wrong answers, finally this one did it for me! Thanks

Comment: If it helps then upvote my  answer.

Answer (score -1):

I am using Linux mint ver. 17.2, 32 bit:

I was getting the message

```
Error mounting system-managed device for DVDRAM............, exited with non-zero exit status 32: mount: wrong fs
```

where the DVD drive does not want to mount the disk

Updating the kernel did not solve my problem, however I applied the following:

1. I opened Disks > Select CD/DVD Drive > obtained drive details > /dev/sr0
2. went to File System > `etc/fstab`
3. opened `fstab' as root in text editor
4. went to `/dev/disk/by-id/ata-HL-DT-ST_DVDRAM_GSA-H60N_K127AU81215 /mnt/ata-HL-DT-#ST_DVDRAM_GSA-H60N_K127AU81215 auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0`
5. typed a # infront,
6. In the next line below I typed:

   ```
   /dev/sr0/ata-HL-DT-ST_DVDRAM_GSA-H60N_K127AU81215
   /mnt/ata-HL-DT-ST_DVDRAM_GSA-H60N_K127AU81215 auto
   nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
   ```

saved and closed.

Tried mounting the DVDRAM as read only > SUCCESS!

Comment: After editing the fstab by inserting a new entry for the DVD rom 
I keep getting the following, at bootup, after doing the process dated 13 Feb 2018:
"keys: Continue to wait, Press S to skip mounting or M for manual recovery." (i have to keep pressing S to continue booting Linux OS from partition)
To sort this out i did the following:
I went back to fstab file, opened as root,  and then put a # infront of 
/dev/sr0/ata-HL-DT-#ST_DVDRAM_GSA-H60N_K127AU81215 /mnt/ata-HL-DT-ST_DVDRAM_GSA-H60N..." so that the system does not attempt to mount the DVD Rom while booting. I saved and closed.

Comment: .... after doing the process dated 12 Feb 2018: